# Sql sum and Merge together

Tags: php, sql, merge, sum

How I can merge same "ProductName" column and sum values in respective "Qty" column based on bill no column?
I've attached my database image. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

I'm trying this, but not working.

```
`SELECT d.billNo,
 d.productName,
 sum(d.productQty) AS qty
 FROM
 bill_detail AS d GROUP BY d.billNo`
```

I want to get each bill no with one time ProductName and with total Qty in that bill no should be total of that bill Qty of that product like in Bill No "1" Elbow Qty should be 9 and same others bills.

Comment: what is your expected output, show us in tabular form?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: You must `group by d.billNo, d.productName`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need 1 more column in your GROUP BY clause

```
 SELECT d.billNo,
        d.productName,
        sum(d.productQty) AS qty
        FROM bill_detail AS d 
        GROUP BY d.billNo, d.productname
```